# django form not validating the datefield

Tags: python, django, forms, validation

I have a form :

```
class AppointmentForm1(forms.Form):

f_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
appointment_date = forms.DateField()

def clean_appointment_date(self):
    appointment_date = self.cleaned_data['appointment_date']
    today = date.today()
    next_week = today + timedelta(days=7)
    if appointment_date is None:
        raise forms.ValidationError("You must provide a date to take appointment")
    if appointment_date < today:
        raise forms.ValidationError("You cannot take appointment on past date")
    if appointment_date > next_week:
        raise forms.ValidationError("You can only take appointment with in one week")
    return appointment_date
```

and I have catched the appointment_date in view..

```
appointment_date = request.GET.get('appointment_date')
app = DoctorAppointment()
app.appointment_date = appointment_date
app.save()
```

I have model named DoctorAppointment.
When I do this and enter whatever value for appointment_date it saves in the database. It doesn't show any error.

In my template I have done:

```
{{ form.appointment_date.errors }}
{{ appointment_form.appointment_date }}
```

Am I doing anything wrong for validating the datefield. The values for `today = date.today()
        next_week = today + timedelta(days=7)` are correct I have printed in the console.

My database for appointment_date is:

```
appointment_date = models.DateField()
```

Need help??
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Why are you doing anything with the `appointment_date` in the view at all? You're already validating it via the form...

Comment: I am just saving it to the model in my view.. not doing anything at all..

Comment: Can you include your entire view above? It would be helpful to see when/where you're saving it.

Comment: why dont you use modelform?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what the question is.  Is something going wrong in your code or are you asking if there are any edge cases you haven't accounted for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have declared form `AppointmentForm1`, but didn't use it

```
appointment_date = request.GET.get('appointment_date')
```

And use POST when you trying to create/update data in your database

```
<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

So in your views should be something like this

```
if request.POST:
    my_form = AppointmentForm1(request.POST)
    if my_form.is_valid():
        appointment_date = my_form.cleaned_data['appointment_date']
        DoctorAppointment.objects.create(appointment_date=appointment_date)

        return HttpResponseRedirect('some_url')
else:
    my_form = AppointmentForm1()

return render(request, 'some_app_name/some_html_name.html', {"form": my_form},
    content_type="application/xhtml+xml")
```